# having issues with laravel 9 breeze , i have hosted it successfully everything working fine ... but breeze login and register wont work on production

Tags: laravel, vue.js, breeze

this is my error on production level
Vite manifest not found at: /home/codarhqc/codar/public/build/manifest.json (View: /home/codarhqc/codar/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php) (View: /home/codarhqc/codar/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php)

Comment: Did you run `npm run prod` in the prod server?

Comment: very part of the web app is working well  100%.. expect login

Comment: no i only ran npm run build

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the following file `bootstrap/cache/config.php` or better if you can make a route in your web.php file with a function that runs: `php artisan optimize:clear`.
This should remove the problem.